# HTML5 persistant storage: Local Storage or SQLite?

Tags: android, ios, html, sqlite

I am in the R&D phase for an application that should run on android and iOs. So I was evaluating the use of HTML5.

However, I need to store some data persistently. I have found a number of articles describing the differences between the HTML5 storage options [Local Storage (=Web Storage), IndexedDB, WebSQL].

What I need are the pros & cons of Local Storage vs. (native) SQLite with HTML5 via JavaScript Interface (I think phoneGap is using a similar approach).

I am interested in following:

- ease of implementation (Android / Ios)
- Storage size limitations
- DB Speed (disregarding WebSQL as it is depreciated)
- persistence (e.g. can someone delete the app local storage when cleaning the browser data?)

Would appretiate to learn from your experiences.

Comment: It depends what type / how much data you are storing. Can we have some details?

Comment: I would like this question to be useful for a wide audience so I did on purpose did not specifiy the use case. Furthermore I do not see the nessecity. If e.g. storage limit for Local Storage is 2MB, a developer can judge for himself. Androdi implementation does not seem too difficult as an interface is provided, iOS I do not know. But I am happy to answer if you can tell me which part is dependend on the requirements.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), Chapter 7, Local Storage.